# php double array loop echo value

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop

I need to create a working function loop that sums the number of 2 arrays.
Using the the following constraint.

Constraints
•   1 ≤ n ≤ 100

Output Format
Sum both array values accordingly 5,1,2,3,4,5=15 and 5,12,12=24 .

Input 1
5
1
2
3
4
5

Output 1
15

Explanation 1
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15, so our function returns 15.

Input 2
2
12
12

Output 2
24

Explanation 2
12 + 12 = 24, so the function returns 24.

The following is what I have done which works for the first array.

```
function sum($numbers) {

$total = 0;

for ($i=0; $i<=5; $i++) {

    echo $i . ""; 
    $total = $total + $numbers[$i]; 

}

echo $total . "";
return $total;

}
```

Comment: Did you just give us your homework assignment?

Comment: can you post a link to the problem, if its online?

Comment: smells like a homework or exercise, its much more fulfilling if you try to solve this alone, after all, you're the one who's going to benefit if you finish it

Comment: its a practice question ive done both parts just not sure how to combine the loops. Im nearlly there just need a bit of help to complete it.

Comment: note: if your function receives an array, treat it as such `$numbers[$i]`

Comment: It is called practice (not ask the Internet) for a reason :] Have a look at [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/array_shift)

Comment: replace the first code `$i=1;` to `$i=0;`  also note the array values denote as `$numbers[$i]; `

Comment: thanks great help Jees K Denny  $numbers[$i]; why did change this make it work?

Comment: [worth reading](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: sorry to say martin nothing to do with homework! saw a function problem online and couldn't work out a solution. i was nearly there just needed a bit of prompting.

Answer (score 0):

The prompt states you need to be summing the elements of the array, but it looks like you're summing the indices.  The first example only works because the indices match the elements.  The second example is just plain wrong... don't hardcode values that can change!

Keep in mind the elements of the array are the values it contains (in example 2 that's 12 and 12), and the indices are the 0-based positions of the values (0 and 1).

Since this is obviously some sort of homework assignment, I'll let you work it out from there.

Comment: its not a homework assignment its a practice question how do i make it so it skip adding the first number in the array eg 12+12=24 and not 26?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp give that a read and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your first paragraph, using the built in function of php **array_sum()** is what you are looking for if you are to output the sum of the given array values.

```
<?php
$array = (1,2,3,4,5);     // Array of integers
$sum = array_sum($array); // A function with one parameter
echo $sum;                // returns 15

AND

$array = (12,12);         // Array of integers
$sum = array_sum($array); // A function with one parameter
echo $sum;                // returns 24
?>
```

Here's the link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php

If you are trying to get the sum of arguments from a function:

```
function args(){
    $arg_nums = func_num_args();    
    $sum = 0;
    for($i = 0 ; $i < $arg_nums; $i++)
        $sum += func_get_arg($i);
    return $sum;
}
echo args(1,2,3,4,5);  // returns 15;
echo args(12,12);      // returns 24
```

Take a look at **func_get_arg()**: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php

Comment: thanks for trying however you answer doesn't solve the required problem!